# string.Format Date conversion issue

Tags: c#, datetime

I am using Windows 8. My culture is "en-IN". but format for date time is MM/dd/yyyy
When trying

```
String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateTime.Today);
```

gives format like 12-29-2012.

Please suggest how can I do.

Comment: You need to be clearer about what's wrong. I've guessed at it in my answer, but it would really help if you'd make the question clearer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not clear what the problem is. If it's just that it's using hyphens instead of slashes, that's presumably because the default date separator for your culture is a hyphen. The options are:

- Explicitly specify a different culture (e.g. the invariant culture)

  ```
  String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateTime.Today);
  ```
- Escape the slashes:

  ```
  String.Format("{0:MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}", DateTime.Today);
  ```

Note that using `DateTime.Today.ToString(...)` would be simpler than using `string.Format` IMO.

Comment: Hah - beat me by seconds..altho I didn't think of escaping the slashes. Good call.

Comment: @jon Skeet- If i change my culture to "en-US" then have i to write "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture" ?

Comment: @HHF: I don't understand what you mean. You may be okay using en-US, but if you want your code to give the same result in all environments, you should be explicit about it anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet : Thank you. Is there a way i can do it for my whole project ?

Comment: @HHF: Centralize where you perform conversions like this. Without more context, it's hard to know whether changing the thread culture would be an appropriate alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yeah - your current culture is used for a lot of format-related settings;

Here, try this:

```
// Change culture
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-IN");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-IN");

// prints 12-29-2012
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateTime.Today));

// Invariant culture, so ignore any culture-based settings
// prints 12/29/2012
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", DateTime.Today));
```

Answer (score 2):

The '/' is the [custom date separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) that is translated accoring to your (or the specified) culture. If you really want slashes, you need to quote them:

```
String.Format("{0:MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}", DateTime.Today);
```

or [escape](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#escape) them:

```
String.Format(@"{0:MM\/dd\/yyyy}", DateTime.Today);
```

Comment: This also works for the `DateTime` string representation. `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy:HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: Why the '/' was selected for the custom date separator is beyond me; but this solved the issue.

Comment: Probably because that's the US date separator, just like the `.` and `,` meaning in number formats

Answer (score 0):

trt this one

```
 DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: like that lblDate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") ?

Answer (score 0):

I Think You Shoud Try This

```
 DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```